# How do you get the main missions to pop up again on gta 5?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

In the xbox 360 version of gta 5. I had just completed the mission "Hang Ten" where trevor kills floyd and his girlfriend and takes over the strip club. After this the main missions wont pop up anymore and i've done all the strangers and freaks missions so im stuck...please help

Answer (score 2):

Continue playing missions with the other characters. You've taken Trevor's main missions as far as you possibly can and need to switch to complete another story dependencies.